# Swift Animation Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton, uilabel

I am trying to move a UILabel and a UIButton onto the screen of my app once something happens, however, when I use an animation to do this, it doesn't work and when the animation is supposed to happen, the components don't move onto the screen. Here is the code for the animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2) { () -> Void in
                    self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.label.center.y)
                    self.again.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.again.center.y)
                }
```

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need some more context — where are you calling this?

Comment: I agree with @TroyT. We need a bit more code as well. Are you creating the objects in the story board?

Comment: No, I created them in main.storyboard with the graphical interface, not programmatically. In viewDidLayoutSubviews, I make the components go off the screen, and then whenever a certain event is executed, and I know when this is executed, the components are supposed to be animated back onto the screen.

Comment: I can post my whole storyboard code

Answer (score 1):

You should try this. Using layoutIfNeeded() will reposition everything.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2) { () -> Void in

                 self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.label.center.y)
                 self.again.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.again.center.y)
                 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work, and I actually made something print to the console during this animation, and it printed, but the components were not moved onto the iPhone screen

Comment: Instead of self.view.layoutIfNeeded() try self.label.layoutIfNeeded() and self.again.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
delay: 2.0,
options: .CurveEaseInOut ,
animations: {
self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.label.center.y)
self.again.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.again.center.y)    },
completion: { finished in
  println("Bug moved left!")
  self.faceBugRight()
})
}
```